# split by special char and remove empty elements in php and javascript array

Tags: php

I have a merged string merged by numbers and each number element has the `&` character in the beginning and end.

Actual string `&1&&3&&5&`
If you add 6 to this string the final string will be `&1&&3&&5&&6&`

The problem is when I want to get numbers in this string of arrays, too many empty element in the array also I don't need them.

When I split `explode(',', actualstr)` the array is `["1","","3","","5","","6"]` but I need this `["1","3","5","6"]`

I will do this many times so need most efficient way.

There is a similar scenario in js too if there is special way need to know, if not it's ok with manual check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading and trailing `&`, then `explode` by double `&&`.

```
$array = explode('&&',trim($str,'&'));
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One quickfix to that is using regex, but only if you know and are 100% about the data you are working with

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", "&1&&3&&5&&6&", $numbers);
var_dump($numbers);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use array filter, if the data between the '&' is not fit for filtering by regex

```
array_filter(explode("&", "&1&&3&&5&&6&"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you extract the number of this string, but if you do like this you can get an array of the numbers:

```
preg_match_all('/&([0-9])&/','&1&&3&&5&',$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

In JavaScript you can do something like @AlexAndrei has done in PHP:

```js
var str='&1&&3&&5&';
var result=str.substr(0,str.length-1).substr(1).split('&&');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim() function to remove a spacial character or removing space character from the string.

```
$str = "&1&&3&&5&&6&";
$str_clear = trim($str, '&');
$array = explode('&&',$str_clear);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
$str = "&1&&3&&5&&6&";
$numArray = preg_split('/&/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($numArray);
```